# Apache 2.4.7 isn't sending 304 response when mod_deflate is enabled

Tags: json, apache, ubuntu, gzip, mod-deflate

I'm running Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu Server 14.04

I have a webserver running. It returns `304 modified` for images, but it doesn't return the same for `json` files. I have checked the answers and comments for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896974/apache-is-not-sending-304-response-if-mod-deflate-and-addoutputfilterbytype-is) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878068/enable-mod-deflate-to-send-content-encoding-gzip), however, they don't work for me.

In my `.conf` file, when I do not load `mod_deflate`, the server returns a `304` response for my `json` file. But when I GZIP this file, the server returns `200 OK`.

This is what I add to my `apache2.conf` file:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
</IfModule>
```

Any workaround to enable both `mod_deflate` and `304` for `.json` files?

Thanks!

Comment: I am also looking for a workaround. I have the very same issue, but also with CSS files and JavaScript source files. Turning off mod_deflate gives 304. [A silly bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45023) from years back has been reopened lately in the Apache bug tracker. [Someone else says](http://codeblow.com/questions/mod-deflate-on-apache-leading-to-browser-to-perform-a-200-rather/) that Etags are to blame. I am continuing investigations.

Comment: Anyone else stumbling on this question might be interested in my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896974/apache-is-not-sending-304-response-if-mod-deflate-and-addoutputfilterbytype-is#comment-49426848

Comment: Don't set ETag to none, see better fix and explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/38617597/960020

Answer (score 1):

Simply set Etag to NONE in apache config.

Having mod_deflate on will append -gzip to Etag, which server then doesn't accept.

Look at the [mod_deflate spec](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_deflate.html)

> AddSuffix Append the compression method onto the end of the ETag,
>   causing compressed and uncompressed representatins to have unique
>   ETags. This has been the default since 2.4.0, but prevents serving
>   "HTTP Not Modified" (304) responses to conditional requests for
>   compressed content.

Comment: I do everything to work, but still get 200 in response instead of 304 with empty content.., etag is removed..Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800 and Last-Modified: Wed, 31 Jan 2024 10:18:43 GMT and i try with curl Last-Modified: Wed, 31 Jan 2024 10:18:43 GMT on a static file on disk...